# Clarity on ggplot_build

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need some clarity on ggplot_build. I am trying to identify the location of the y axis limits so I can expand the plot by rounding up the upper y limit. I know how to access parts of the ggplot_build and make the changes I want, but it looks like multiple elements could change the plot limits. Which one below will change the limits of the ggplot or do all 3 need to be edited?

1. layout -> coord -> limits -> y
2. layout -> panel_scales_y-> [[1]] -> range
3. plot -> coordinates -> limits -> y

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question but it sounds like  `scale_y_continuous(limits = c(lower limit, upper limit))` or  `scale_y_discrete(limits = c(lower limit, upper limit))`. An example would help

Comment: I already have gg = ggplot() coded, and then I call ggplot_build(gg). I am trying to determine which of the three elements I should edit from ggplot_build(gg) to change the y-axis of the plots. I need to do this since the y-axis limits from ggplot() could change between my datasets, so using scale_y_discrete isn't an option for me.